# ¿como detectar teclas en segundo plano?

Tags: c#

Estoy creando una pequeña aplicación en c# que detecte cuando pulso las teclas "Ctrl+c" y me muestre un mensaje. Mi intención es que me detecte estas teclas aun estando otra aplicación en primer plano y ella en segundo. ¿Alguien puede guiarme un poco?

Gracias!

Comment: ¿En qué se diferencia con esta pregunta tuya, anteriormente formulada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/177422/duda-con-aplicaci%c3%b3n-en-segunda-pantalla-c?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español @Claudio Riquelme. Has el [tour] para saber como funcionamos. Ve a [ask] para orientarte acerca de cómo hacer preguntas que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y motiven las respuestas que buscas. Para lograr lo que quieres debes entender el concepto **subclass** y ligar retrollamados (CallBacks) al kernel de windows. Tres cosas que no se pueden exponer de modo simple. Trabaja un poco sobre el tema y cuando hayas intentado y probado código, no dudes en taer tus preguntas.